# Как в iOS влиять на воспроизведение видео в браузере и запретить вызов стандартного плеера?

Tags: html, ios, webbrowser, видео

Ситуация: на веб-странице есть видео. Пользователь запускает воспроизведение.

На андроиде видео проигрывается непосредственно на веб-странице. НО на iOS вызывается стандартный проигрыватель и видео воспроизводится в нем.

Как избежать этого сценария? Необходимо чтобы работало таким же образом как на андроиде.

Зачем? В видео на первых секундах проигрывается рекламное видео (как на ютюбе). Получается что в iOS плеере можно промотать рекламный ролик. А этого необходимо избежать.

Answer (score 2):

На html странице добавить атрибут webkit-playsinline для видеотэга (код может варьироваться в зависимости от того, как описан видеотэг):

```
('video').attr('webkit-playsinline', '');
```

или

```
_videotag.setAttribute('webkit-playsinline', '');
```

или

```
<video ... webkit-playsinline>
...
</video>
```

В `UIWebView` добавить:

```
self.webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
```